# Localization of polynomial rings over Prufer domains

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

While I was searching about polynomial ring extensions over Prufer domains it came to me the following question:

> Let $D$ be a Prufer domain and $M$ a maximal ideal of $D$. Then, is $D[X]_{M[X]}$ a valuation ring?

If we set $S=D\setminus M$, then clearly $M[X]\cap S=\emptyset$, so by known results about localizations we get $$D[X]_{M[X]}\cong(D[X]_M)_{(M[X]_M)}\cong(D_M[X])_{(MD_M[X])}.$$

By the hypothesis we have that $D_M$ is a valuation ring, so in particular $D_M$ is a GCD domain, then $(D_M[X])_{M[X]_M}$ is also a GCD domain, but from here I'm unable to conclude anything else about $(D_M[X])_{M[X]_M}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can start with $(D,M)$ a valuation ring, and ask if $R=D[X]_{M[X]}$ is also a valuation ring. Now identify the field of fractions of $R$, say $Q$, and show that any $z\in Q$ satisfies: $z\in R$ or $z^{-1}\in R$.

Comment: This is called the *trivial extension* of $v$ to $K(X)$, where $v$ is a valuation on a field $K$. It is defined by $w(f/g)=w(f)-w(g)$, $f,g\in K[X]$, and $w(a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n)=\min\{v(a_i): a_i\ne0\}$.

Comment: @user26857 thank you for your comments. It seems that you're the only user interested in my questions. Btw, do you know any reference for the results you mentioned and similar?

Comment: See Gilmer, 18.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the isomorphisms given in my question it's enough to show that $(D_M[X])_{(MD_M[X])}$ is a valuation ring. In order to prove this let's take two non-zero elements $F,G\in (D_M[X])_{(MD_M[X])}$.

By definition we can write $$F=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i}{\sum_{j=0}^m b_jX^j}, \;\; G=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^r c_iX^i}{\sum_{j=0}^s d_jX^j},$$ where $a_i,b_j,c_i,d_j\in D_M$ and $\sum_{j=0}^m b_jX^j, \sum_{j=0}^s d_jX^j\notin MD_M[X]$. We then define $$h_1=\sum_{k=0}^{n+s} \alpha_kX^k=\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^s d_jX^j\Bigr),\;\; h_2=\sum_{l=0}^{r+m} \beta_lX^l=\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^r c_iX^i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^m b_jX^j\Bigr)$$

As $D_M$ is a valuation ring, then one of the $\alpha_k$ is a gcd of $\alpha_0,\ldots, \alpha_{n+s}$. WLOG let's suppose that $\alpha_0=\gcd(\alpha_0,\ldots, \alpha_{n+s})$. Anagolously, let's suppose that $\beta_0=\gcd(\beta_0,\ldots, \beta_{r+m})$. Then we have that either $\alpha_0\mid \beta_0$ or $\beta_0\mid \alpha_0$.

Let's assume the later case is true, so there exists $\gamma\in D_M$ such that $\alpha_0=\gamma\beta_0$. Therefore $$H=\frac{h_1}{h_2}=\frac{\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^s d_jX^j\Bigr)}{\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^r c_iX^i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^m b_jX^j\Bigr)}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n+s} \alpha_kX^k}{\sum_{l=0}^{r+m} \beta_lX^l}=\frac{\alpha_0 \Bigl(\sum_{k=0}^{n+s} \alpha'_kX^k\Bigr)}{\beta_0 \Bigl(\sum_{l=0}^{r+m} \beta'_lX^l\Bigr)}=\frac{\gamma\Bigl(\sum_{k=0}^{n+s} \alpha'_kX^k\Bigr)}{\sum_{l=0}^{r+m} \beta'_lX^l}$$

satisfies that $H\in (D_M[X])_{(MD_M[X])}$ because $\beta'_0=1\notin MD_M$. Moreover it's easy to see that $F=GH$, then $G\mid F$ in $(D_M[X])_{(MD_M[X])}$. Hence, $(D_M[X])_{(MD_M[X])}$ is a valuation ring and we're done.